# css3 resize: change height & width smaller

Tags: css

I can resize the iframe's width & height bigger, but if I want to resize it smaller than 150px, it failed. How to deal with it?

Thanks.

```css
.frm{
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    resize:both;
  }
```

```html
<iframe class="frm">
    
</iframe>
```

Comment: [CSS3 resize ignoring min-width/height properties](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72841)

Comment: thks, maybe I have to use jquery ui to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the user agent restrict the resizing to the original width and height, but I did this workaround that should do what you want.

```css
.frm{
    background-color:lightblue;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    resize:both;
  }
.frm:active {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="frm">
    
</iframe>
```

Comment: thks.
I run it , but it has a terrible user experience.
When I click on the border for the first time, the iframe resize to 1x1,and it made me difficult to continue to  resize the iframe by flashing iframe. Is there any ways to solve it without javascript?

Comment: What you want can't be done just with CSS. This is a workaround.